# border not appearing in IE

Tags: html, css

I seee the bottom border in chrome but not in IE8. How to fix this in IE8?

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a doctype `<!DOCTYPE html`> at the top of your file and include the `<html>` and `<body>` elements and it should work. You're triggering quirks mode by not using a doctype.